# Google sheets arrayformula and ranges rules

Tags: google-sheets

I was looking a the formula for cumulative sum using arrayformula:

`ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(ROW(A1:A10), "<=" & ROW(A1:A10), B1:B10))`

I used arrayformulas before, but mostly for simple arithmetic, so I am trying to wrap my head around this.

The reason it is unclear for me is that I don't know what the rules are for `ARRAYFORMULA` to use the range, or to use the scalar value.

If I tabulate it it becomes something like this:

```
row 1: SUMIF(ROW(A1:A10), "<=" & ROW(A1), B1:B10))
row 2: SUMIF(ROW(A1:A10), "<=" & ROW(A2), B1:B10))
...
row n: SUMIF(ROW(A1:A10), "<=" & ROW(An), B1:B10))
```

But that doesn't actually work because `ROW` doesn't work like that if not used in an `ARRAYFORMULA`, according to the docs:

`ROW([cell_reference])
if cell_reference is a range more than one cell wide and the formula is not used as an array formula, only the numeric value of the first row in cell_reference is returned.`

Looking at the syntax for `SUMIF` it is:
`SUMIF(range, criterion, [sumrange])`.

Do I understand it correctly that the rules for `ARRAYFORMULA` are:

- If a function parameter inside `ARRAYFORMULA` is expected to be a scalar (criterion in the examle) and a range is given it will expand in the cells below iterating this range
- If a function parameter inside `ARRAYFORMULA` is expected to be a range (range and sumrange) and a range is given it will pass on the range to the formula

So, the question is:

What is exactly happening row by row with the formula pasted above and how does `ROW` behave in this? `ROW` is 'aware' that it is being used in an arrayformula and behaves differently?

Comment: I like your question and don't have an answer for it. But if your formula isn't working, try `=arrayformula(sum(if([condition],B1:B10,0)))`.

Comment: It's not about the `ROW`. Its more about the `&` and the strings used. Used inside a arrayformula, it creates series(a array) of strings. So, `"<="&ROW(A1:A10)` becomes `"<1"`,`"<2"` and so on. Criterion of SUMIF expects a string and only a single string. Given the array, it creates a array of results for each criterion, the Range argument being the same for each criterion. Also, SUMIF already expects array for the  range argument.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the `ROW`. Its more about the `&` and the strings used. Used inside a arrayformula, it creates series(a array) of strings. So, `"<="&ROW(A1:A10)` becomes `"<1"`,`"<2"` and so on. Criterion argument of `SUMIF` expects a string and only a single string. Given the array, it creates a array of results for each criterion, the Range argument being the same for each criterion. Also, `SUMIF` already expects array for the range argument.